# Windows Canon Raw Codec

Tags: canon, software, raw, windows

Is there a codec to view thumbnails for Canon CR2 files in windows explorer. I have install the microsoft camera codec pack and looked on the Canon website here:

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/digital_cameras/software_applications/canon_raw_codec_software#DriversAndSoftware

But there doesn't appear to be anything to download.

Comment: It is *supposed* to work but I have never been able to get it to. My solution has been to instal *IrfanView* and the RAW plugins available from the Irfanview website and set file associations so that when I click on a .cr2 file in windows explorer it opens in IrfanView. The application is just as fast as the Windows photo preview and also allows you to move forward or backwards through images within a folder.

Comment: Glad I stopped by here. Thanks for the tip @MichaelClark, I've used _IrFanView_ but didn't really know about the plugins. That's wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Canon website, look under 'software' rather than drivers. Download and install the Canon RAW Codec 1.11.0

Alternatively, you can try FastPictureViewer, which is a 3rd party codec pack that support lots of raw file types including Canon. It also supports PSD, which is nice as well if you use Photoshop. There is a trial version to try, otherwise its $10 (March 2015)

http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/

Comment: Completely forgot to mention, I have now found the codec on the canon website, under software. It doesn't show up if you select a 64bit OS, you have to select 32bit, but it works fine for 64bit. Thanks, marking this as answer :)